# $form_state['values'] partial empty, while $form_state['input'] is filled

Tags: 7, forms

I would like extend an existing (altered) form. For this case, I created a new form with the Form API:

```
function my_new_form($form, &$form_state) {
  ...
}
```

In the next step, I get the existing form, which one I would like to extend:

```
function my_new_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form = drupal_get_form('my_form');
}
```

Now, I extended the form with fields like this :

```
function my_new_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form = drupal_get_form('my_form');

  $form['foo'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#size' => 30,
    '#title' => t('foo bar'),
  );

  // and so on..

  return $form;
}
```

In my Template, I display the form:

```
print drupal_render(drupal_get_form('my_new_form'));
```

This works correctly, but after submitting the form, the values from the form from which I extend in the `$form_state['values']` are empty. But in `$form_state['input']` they are existing.

Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try [`drupal_build_form()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/drupal_build_form/7) instead of `drupal_get_form()`.

Comment: Did not work, still the same issue here. The values are empty

Comment: And what about just call `my_form($form, $form_state);` instead of `drupal_get_form()`?

Comment: I have already tried this without success, sadly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason [drupal_get_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/7) doesn't work in your code is that it contains the following code.

```
  $form_state = array();

  $args = func_get_args();
  // Remove $form_id from the arguments.
  array_shift($args);
  $form_state['build_info']['args'] = $args;

  return drupal_build_form($form_id, $form_state);
```

What the function passes to the form builder is a newly created `$form_state` array, not the one being passed to your form builder.

Using [drupal_build_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_build_form/7) is not working because the function is retrieving the form from the cache. (See the comments before the code.)

```
  // If the incoming input contains a form_build_id, we'll check the cache for a
  // copy of the form in question. If it's there, we don't have to rebuild the
  // form to proceed. In addition, if there is stored form_state data from a
  // previous step, we'll retrieve it so it can be passed on to the form
  // processing code.
  $check_cache = isset($form_state['input']['form_id']) && $form_state['input']['form_id'] == $form_id && !empty($form_state['input']['form_build_id']);
  if ($check_cache) {
    $form = form_get_cache($form_state['input']['form_build_id'], $form_state);
  }
```

You can implement [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7), [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7), or [hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter/7) for a form that has been already altered.

About calling `drupal_get_form()` from a template file, see [Be careful with drupal_get_form() in theme layer](http://pixeljets.com/ru/blog/be-careful-drupalgetform-theme-layer). As reported in that blog article, you would have problems with the validation error messages which will not appear.

Answer (score 2):

I can't imagine calling `drupal_get_form()` form inside another form function will produce very good results. If you want to alter an existing form, even one you've declared yourself, you should use [`hook_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) instead:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'my_form') {
    $form['foo'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#size' => 30,
      '#title' => t('foo bar'),
    );
  }
}
```

Doing it that way you should find all of the expected values in the `$form_state` array when the form is submitted/validated.

Comment: "I can't imagine calling..." — I saw something similar in core `user_register_form()` where `user_account_form()` is called: http://drupalcode.org/project/drupal.git/blob/30d1e719aa5e9a9ad66514078ca3b0975ddadc9c:/modules/user/user.module#l3704

Comment: `user_account_form()` is not a form builder function (`drupal_get_form()` is never called with it as a parameter), it's a: _"Helper function to add default user account fields to user registration and edit form."_. Plus the OP is calling `drupal_get_form()`, not another form builder function directly, from within a function that itself is run through `drupal_get_form()`. This is where the problems are happening

Comment: I have a form that users can use to register on my webpage. users can register by using 2 options. one simple ajax popup registration on the home page and one that contains additional  fields. both containing the same layout and field settings. So I cant use hook_form_alter since this alters both forms?

Answer (score 0):

Usually all the game about population `$form_state['values']` from `$form_state['input']` is concluded with correct setting `$form['some_input']['#tree']` parameter, which affects form builder to fill the `$form['some_input']['#parents']`. So `$form['some_input']['#parents']` has the direct influence of correct populating `$form_state['input']` into `$form_state['values']`
In most cases `#tree = FALSE` to all elements (no matter how deep they are nested) is enought for correct populating. 
Here you can read some about this https://www.drupal.org/node/48643
This "problem" is not clear to me totally, i still get results with experiments :)

For nested elements is better to set #tree = TRUE to thier direct parent only.
For example `$from['users_list']['action_selected']['user_id1'] ...['user_idN']` here is `['action_selected']` must be #tree=true, and you will have in $form_state['values'] grouped by ['action_selected'] as subarray of ['user_idN'] values, assuming that ['user_idN'] is HTML input field